# particles.js not loading on page correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles

HTML script

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json',
    function(){
        console.log('particles.json loaded...')
    })
</script>
```

CSS for the particles

```
#particles-js {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0ac8f8, #081866);
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Now whenever I load the page I get these errors (in the console):

```
particles.min.js:9 Failed to load file:///G:/actualtest/particles.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
window.particlesJS.load @ particles.min.js:9
(anonymous) @ home.html:66
particles.min.js:9 Error pJS - XMLHttpRequest status: 0
particles.min.js:9 Error pJS - File config not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TemaniAfif pointed out, there is a missing comma here:

```
<script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json'
    function(){
        console.log('particles.json loaded...')'
    })
</body>
```

...because the inline function at the bottom is [supposed](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/#usage) to be a parameter of the particleJS.load function call. And it needs a closing script tag. Try replacing the above with:

```
<script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json',
    function(){
        console.log('particles.json loaded...')'
    })
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and am now getting an unexpected or invalid token error in the console though, i guess its progress however.

Comment: Good to know, just sounds like an authentication issue now.

Answer (score 1):

please try following code:

```
<script>
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json',
    function(){
        console.log("particles.json loaded...");
    });
</script>
```

Did you saved the "particle.json" file correctly in your root directory where your application runs?

Comment: added my json config into edit, and yes its in the root directory where my application is running @SnowBallz