# loading config for particles.js

Tags: javascript, json, virtual-directory, particles.js

I have a simple web page see here that attempts to implement particles.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    #particles {
    background: black;
    height: 100vh;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="particles-js">

    </div>
</body>

<script src=
"./assets/ParticleJS/particles.js-master/particles.min.js">
</script>
<script src=
"./assets/ParticleJS/particles.js-master/demo/js/app.js">
</script>
<script>
    var particlesJS;
    
    /* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'http://localhost/jsonconfig/particles/particlesjs-config.json', function() {
    console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
    });

</script>
</html>
```

The above code is me creating a VirtualDirectory on my localhost default web site in iis and pointing that VirtualDirectory to the file where my JSON is stored. I did this trying to get around a CORS error by making it point to HTTP:// instead of file://.

I get the below error.
[image]

my original solution pointed the where a copy of the JSON was in my root directory.

```
<script>
    var particlesJS;
    
    /* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', './particlesjs-config.json', function() {
    console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
    });

</script>
```

I got a CORS error
[image]

***EDIT***
I forgot to include I also tried this to get around the CORS error

```
<script>
    var particlesJS;
    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                /* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */
                particlesJS.load('particles-js', this.responseText, function() {
                console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
    });
        }
    };

   xhttp.open('GET', 'http://localhost/jsonconfig/particles/particlesjs-config.json');
   xhttp.send();

</script>
```

I received a similar error with CORS
[image]

I just can't seem to get around this cors error, any and all help would be appreciated.

Resources I accessed: 
https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/ 
[particles.js not loading on page correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338522/particles-js-not-loading-on-page-correctly)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-particle-js-in-javascript-project/ 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/314369/xmlhttprequest-getting-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-e.html
https://community.intersystems.com/post/access-xmlhttprequest-httplocalhost52773irisvscodeapptest-origin-null-has-been-blocked-cors 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference 
https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#For_IIS7

***EDIT***
I added this web.config file to the root directory of the iis site I was using to host the .json file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

I still get a CORS error when trying to access the config file from http://localhost/jsonconfig/particles/particlesjs-config.json.

I even tried for giggles including the web.config file in the directory of the site I am trying to load the config.json file for.

Comment: _"how or if I can get around it"_ - You will definitely find similar questions and many answers that will solve that problem if you do some research here on SO or your preferred search provider.

Comment: Why "localhost"? Try to remove `http://localhost`.

Comment: to remove the file:// since I thought this was something like not allowed to redirect to local resource in chrome. I made a VirtualDirectory on IIS that pointed to the location where the .json file is located. That way I could use Http:// to grab the file.

Comment: You should serve your files, even if you develop localy, from a  "real" webserver. Avoid "file://"

Comment: Is this a limitation with using IIS? Just to confirm.